# JVM closes while using a continous Thread for no reason

Tags: java, multithreading, file, timer, directory

I am experiencing a Problem with my Program.
I am trying to sort downloaded files by their ending. So far I've got the structure for observing a given File path and listing those files within an `HashSet`.
My problem now is, that the program keeps running for a few seconds but then ends with the exit code 0 so everything should be fine.

```
public class WatchDir {

    protected HashSet<File> hashSetOfFiles;
    protected String filePath = "";

    public WatchDir() {

        chooseFilePath();
        if (filePath.isEmpty())
            return;

        listAnfangFiles();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                listNewFiles();
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        }.start();
    }

    private void listNewFiles() {

        File file = new File(filePath);

        for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
            if (hashSetOfFiles.add(f)) {
                newFileFound(f);
            }
        }
    }

    private void newFileFound(File f) {

        // Hier kommen alle neuen Dateien an
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }

    private void listAnfangFiles() {

        hashSetOfFiles = new HashSet<File>();
        File f = new File(filePath);

        for (File ff : f.listFiles()) {
            hashSetOfFiles.add(ff);
        }
    }

    private void chooseFilePath() {
        //
        // JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        // chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        //
        // if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        // filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

        filePath = "C:\\Users\\maurice\\Desktop\\Test";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WatchDir();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            listNewFiles();
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }.start();
```

It is not a continuous thread.
In the `run()` method, you have not a loop condition which allows the thread to go on running in continuous.
So `sleep(1000);` is played once and it is the last played instruction in your `run()` method. After the return of it, the `run()` method has terminated and the thread is therefore ended.

---

**Edit** : a simple solution for having a continuous thread

For example, this code allows the thread never stops, but a process termination :

```
 new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            while (true){
               listNewFiles();
               try {
                   sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }

        };
    }.start();
```

You could have other conditions to stop the loop (a delay, a date or a time, a state, a pressed key, etc...). To allow it, you should put it in the `while()` condition or in a block `if (condition) break`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean wantToContinue = true;
    new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        while (wantToContinue){
           listNewFiles();
           try {
               sleep(1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

    };
}.start();
```

use boolean variable . So you can control the action from outside. Giving true  condition is not good practice.